# Python how to evaluate if one of two substrings in string using OR operator

Tags: python, logical-operators

I am trying to write part of a script that will evaluate whether or not any of two (or more) given characters are present in a string. It seems that the logical OR operator is always true in my IF/IN sentence. Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
mylist = ['abc', 'def']
for mystring in mylist:
    if 'a' in mystring:
        print mystring
    if 'a' or 'b' in mystring:
        print mystring

prints:
abc
abc
def
```

Comment: why are you checking "if 'a' in mystring" if you want to check if two or more characters are in a string? What output are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that `'a'` always evaluates to `True` and you are saying: "is `'a'` True or is `'b' in mystring` True".

```
def is_chars_in_strings(strings, chars):
    answer = []
    for string in strings:
        a = False
        for char in chars:
            if char in string:
                a = True
                break
        if not a:
            answer.append(string)
    return answer

print (is_chars_in_strings(['abc', 'def'], 'ab'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement: `if 'a' or 'b' in mystring` is the same as: `if ('a') or ('b' in mystring)`, resulting in True for all cases, as `if 'a':` is always true.

You can solve this problem by using list comprehensions:

```
 if any([c in mystring for c in 'ab']):
   ...
```